# How to load again a Fragment in FrameLayout?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

Lets say I have category A and B. I load data in a `RecyclerView` depending on category. Then there is a filter, which actually filters the content. 
Here is what I do when filter is opened/closed:

```
@Override
        public void onShowSheet() {
            Fragment f = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.filterContent);
            if (!(f instanceof FilterFragment)) {
                FilterFragment filterFragment = FilterFragment.newInstance();
                FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.filterContent, filterFragment, "FilterFragment");
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onHideSheet() {
            Fragment f = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.filterContent);
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
                    remove(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.filterContent)).commit();
            FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
            trans.remove(f);
            trans.commit();
        }
    });
```

When filter is reopened, it reloads the filter fragment and its data.

When I change the category, and open filter, it shows blank.

How can I load or kill the fragment, so that it does not show blank?

---

Update

After I change the category and the filter is blank, I press Back Key and I get back to previews category, and the filter is shown, but the application crashes if I try to apply the filter.

When I change the category, I reload the fragment with data:

```
public static void inflateGridFragment() {
    GridFragment fragment = new GridFragment();
    FragmentManager fm = context.getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right,
            R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.mdContent, fragment, Strings.TAG_GRID_FRAMGMENT);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(Strings.TAG_GRID_FRAMGMENT);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: onShowSheet and onHideSheet, are they in an Activity or Fragment ?

Comment: Inside the Fragment which has `RecyclerView`

Comment: actually what is these onShowSheet, what library you using, what is the interface you implementing?

Comment: I am using MaterialSheetFab Library: https://github.com/gowong/material-sheet-fab

Comment: In your Fragment, can you try to use getChildFragmentManager() instead of getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager() ?

Comment: I did, the application crashes when the sheet closes

Comment: now I found out the problem is in parent fragment. I should not reinflate the fragment if it is already in backstack, and the filter works. But I am not sure how to find the specific fragment in backstack and go back to it.

Comment: Close this question and create a new one, or update your question if you are asking something else

Comment: Actually I found the solution, should I post the answer?

Comment: Yes, post the answer and after a delay you'll be able to mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when changing from category A to B, I was reloading the parent fragment which hosts the Filters fragment. So, when changing the category, I check if fragment which contains `RecyclerView` is in backstack, then I do popBackStack`to that fragment, and update the data from`RecyclerView` as follows:

```
boolean foundGridFragment = false;
        String fragmentBackstackTag = "";
        FragmentManager fm = context.getSupportFragmentManager();
        for(int entry = 0; entry < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); entry++){
            fragmentBackstackTag = fm.getBackStackEntryAt(entry).getName();
            Log.i(TAG, "Found fragment: " + fragmentBackstackTag);

            // check if null, because sometimes fragmentBackstacktag may null
            if (fragmentBackstackTag != null) {
                if (fragmentBackstackTag.equals(Strings.TAG_GRID_FRAMGMENT)) {
                    foundGridFragment = true;
                    fm.popBackStack(Strings.TAG_GRID_FRAMGMENT, 0);
                }
            }
        }
        if (!foundGridFragment) {
            inflateGridFragment();
        }
```

This also optimizes the memory usage.